# How can know the configure file belong to which package?

Tags: debian, package-management

There are two major samba packages in debian: samba ,samba-common.The configuration file is `/etc/samba/smb.conf`,how can know `/etc/samba/smb.conf` belong to which package--samba or samba-common? (i already know it contained in samba-common)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Files under `/etc/` are often not shipped directly in packages but managed by “maintainer scripts”. These are all stored in `/var/lib/dpkg/info`; those which run during installation have names ending in `inst`.

The first thing to try is still a package search:

```
dpkg -S /etc/samba/smb.conf
```

In this instance, this won‘t find anything. (When this command returns matches, check the matched file name as well since matches can be partial.)

We need to look at the maintainer scripts:

```
$ grep smb.conf /var/lib/dpkg/info/*inst
/var/lib/dpkg/info/samba-common-bin.postinst:        echo "Checking smb.conf with samba-tool"
/var/lib/dpkg/info/samba-common-bin.postinst:        echo "Checking smb.conf with testparm"
/var/lib/dpkg/info/samba-common.postinst:NEWFILE=$TEMPDIR/smb.conf
/var/lib/dpkg/info/samba-common.postinst:CONFIG=/etc/samba/smb.conf
/var/lib/dpkg/info/samba-common.postinst:configure_smb_conf() {
/var/lib/dpkg/info/samba-common.postinst:       configure_smb_conf "$CONFIG"
/var/lib/dpkg/info/samba-common.postinst:cp /usr/share/samba/smb.conf "$NEWFILE"
/var/lib/dpkg/info/samba-common.postinst:configure_smb_conf "$NEWFILE"
/var/lib/dpkg/info/samba-common.postinst:       echo " sudo cp /usr/share/samba/smb.conf $CONFIG"
```

The file is created by `samba-common.postinst`, so the package responsible for it is `samba-common`. The package ships an initial configuration file in `/usr/share/samba/smb.conf`, and installs that as `/etc/samba/smb.conf`; it uses [`ucf`](https://manpages.debian.org/bullseye/ucf/ucf.1) to merge user settings, such as the workgroup name, into it if appropriate, and to deal with changes on upgrade. When the package is purged, the removal maintainer script takes care of removing `/etc/samba/smb.conf` along with any state maintained by `ucf`.